# List of lines from file in Python?

Tags: python, list

Is there a way to read the lines of a file and convert it to a Python list? For example:

someFile:

```
Hello
World
```

Script:

```
>>>x = someFile.listLines()
>>>print x
['Hello', 'World']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `readlines` method of a `file` object.

```
fileobject = open(datafilename)
lines = fileobject.readlines()
```

Note that you (usually) don't need this.  You can iterate over the file object directly and save yourself from having to store the whole file in memory:

```
for line in fileobject:
    #do something with the line
```

*don't forget to close your fileobject when you're done!* (context managers are quite helpful for that)

Also, note that the lines will end with a newline (`"\n"`), but you can easily filter that off using `.rstrip("\n")` on the strings in the list or some variant in the `str.strip` family.  e.g.:

```
stripped_lines = [ line.rstrip("\n") for line in fileobject ]
```

---

In other words,

```
lines = fileobject.readlines()
```

gives you the same thing as

```
lines = list(fileobject)
```

Comment: If I did the second one (`for line in fileobject`), the string `line` would be the text of the line of the file it's currently reading?

Comment: A note: you'll probably want to trim the lines as they'll have a terminating `\n`